# Does Schema depend on first row while converting RDD to DataFrame in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My Question is while converting from Rdd to dataframe in pyspark does the schema depends on the first row ?

```
data1  = [('A','abc',0.1,'',0.562),('B','def',0.15,0.5,0.123),('A','ghi',0.2,0.2,0.1345),('B','jkl','',0.1,0.642),('B','mno',0.1,0.1,'')]
>>> val1=sc.parallelize(data1).toDF()
>>> val1.show()
+---+---+----+---+------+
| _1| _2|  _3| _4|    _5|
+---+---+----+---+------+
|  A|abc| 0.1|   | 0.562|  <------ Does it depends on type of this row?
|  B|def|0.15|0.5| 0.123|
|  A|ghi| 0.2|0.2|0.1345|
|  B|jkl|null|0.1| 0.642|
|  B|mno| 0.1|0.1|  null|
+---+---+----+---+------+

>>> val1.printSchema()
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _5: double (nullable = true)
```

As you can see column **_4** should have been **double** but it considered as **string**.

> Any Suggestions will be helpfull.
>   Thanks!

Comment: Having spark infer the schema is seldom a good idea since you rarely can expect the data to be 100% consistent. In this case, it would be better to use a case class instead of a generic tuple to define your rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Prathik, I think you are right. 
`toDF()` is a shorthand for `spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema, sampleRatio)`.

Here's the signature for `createDataFrame`:

```
def createDataFrame(self, data, schema=None, samplingRatio=None, verifySchema=True)
```

So by default, the parameters `schema` and `samplingRatio` are `None`.
[According to the doc](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L626):

> If schema inference is needed, `samplingRatio` is used to determined the ratio of
>           rows used for schema inference. The first row will be used if `samplingRatio` is `None`.

So by default, `toDF()` will use the first row to infer the data type, which it figures `StringType` for column 4, but `FloatType` for column 5.

Here you can't specify the schema to be `FloatType` for column 4 and 5, since they have strings in their columns. 
But you can try set `sampleRatio` to `0.3` as below:

```
data1  = [('A','abc',0.1,'',0.562),('B','def',0.15,0.5,0.123),('A','ghi',0.2,0.2,0.1345),('B','jkl','',0.1,0.642),('B','mno',0.1,0.1,'')]
val1=sc.parallelize(data1).toDF(sampleRatio=0.3)
val1.show()
val1.printSchema()
```

Some times the above code will throw out error if it happens to sample the string row

```
Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>
```

but if you are patient and try more times (< 10 for me), you may get something like this. And you can see that both column 4 and 5 are `FloatType`, because by luck, the program picked `double` numbers while running `createDataFrame`.

```
+---+---+----+----+------+
| _1| _2|  _3|  _4|    _5|
+---+---+----+----+------+
|  A|abc| 0.1|null| 0.562|
|  B|def|0.15| 0.5| 0.123|
|  A|ghi| 0.2| 0.2|0.1345|
|  B|jkl|null| 0.1| 0.642|
|  B|mno| 0.1| 0.1|  null|
+---+---+----+----+------+

root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _4: double (nullable = true)
 |-- _5: double (nullable = true)
```